# AngularJS ng-include failover

Tags: angularjs

I would like to show a default html content when an ng-include directive fails to fetch the resource.

The server returns the http status code 500 or 440 when angular fetches the include source, the failure is ignored and no content is displayed in place of the include directive. There are multiple include directives in my application and I would like to display a different message for each one.

Comment: The `ng-include` doesn't support that. You may have to write a custom directive that wrap `ng-include` and perform the logic in your directive.

Comment: As @runTarm points out, you will need to create a custom directive. If you provide a plunkr or a jsfiddle I will be glad to help you achieve that. rgds

Comment: A custom directive would be particularly elegant solution. I suppose we could catch the $includeContentError event, but I don't know how. Here is a playground http://plnkr.co/edit/OnUWdvpM1ErbL9UlJJRp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion failover is implemented by a custom directive built on top of `ng-include`. It matches elements, attributes and classes.

```
<my-include src="'template1.html'">Failure message</my-include>
<div my-include="'template1.html'">Failure message</div>
<div class="my-include" src='"template1.html"'>Failure message</div>
```

The matched element is replaced by the following template, made of the `ng-include` directive, plus an error message displayed if the template loading failed.

```
<div ng-include='myInclude||src'></div><div ng-show='loadFailed' ng-transclude/>
```

The template source name is either provided by the `src` attribute or by the `my-include` attribute, so that the new directive works the same way as `ng-include` when matching an attribute.

The transclusion mechanism gets error message from the original element children and  replaces the template elements with a `ng-transclude` attribute. This error message is  displayed only if `loadFailed==true` thanks to the `ng-show` directive.

`loadFailed` state is part of the directive scope. It is updated when catching `$includeContentLoaded` and `$includeContentError` events emitted by `ng-include`.

Here is the source code of the module definition:

```
angular.module('includeExample', [])
  .directive("myInclude", function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'CAE',
        scope: {
          src: '=',
          myInclude: '='
        },
        transclude:true,
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
          scope.$on("$includeContentError", function(event, args){
            scope.loadFailed=true;
           });
          scope.$on("$includeContentLoaded", function(event, args){
            scope.loadFailed=false;
          });
        },
        template: "<div ng-include='myInclude||src'></div><div ng-show='loadFailed' ng-transclude/>"
      };
    })
  ;
```

Complete code source http://plnkr.co/edit/3maeSraP4Ddv1lewBUdy

Comment: Your directive work well but it adds an isolated scope in between, breaking the scope inheritance=> The scope of the included template will not a child of the outside scope. I corrected your directive by setting  `scope: true` and watching src and dwInclude attributes:  `scope.$watch(iAttrs.dwInclude, function (v) {
        scope.dwInclude = v;
      });
      scope.$watch(iAttrs.src, function (v) {
        scope.src = v;
      });`