# ngInclude use default path if file doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to include a file using ngInclude.
My issue is, I want to load a custom view. if this customView doesn't exist, I want to use the default one.

I have a piece of code working, but I think I can do really better... I would like to use a directive, I think it is much better.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="include-container" ng-include="{{ mainViewUrl }}"></div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$http.get('customView.html').then(function success(response) {
            $scope.mainView = "'customView.html'";
        }, function error(response) {
            $scope.mainView = "'defaultView.html'";
        });
```

Thanks for your help, Hopefully it's not a duplicate question...

**EDIT:**

I've found this part of solution : [AngularJS ng-include failover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391279/angularjs-ng-include-failover)
Here the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3maeSraP4Ddv1lewBUdy?p=info)

I would like, on the fail, load my default url. Any idea ?

**EDIT2 :**

I would like to do something like that:

```
<div class="include-container" ng-include="customView.html || defaultView.html"></div>
```

Comment: seems like that would load it twice. can you inject in a string instead of a file? you already have the file contents as a string in the `get` part, which if that's not needed (its not in the code shown), should be a HEAD request instead of a GET

Comment: I would start by putting the call in a factory. What does response contain for data. I mean, you don't use it. Why not? You should not use a directive for http calls. Directives should be dumb components in your app.

Comment: I would rather use something else than an http call if possible :) That's the only way I've found so far... I'll update my question to show a directive I used but don't do enough for me

Answer (score 0):

Put the response into `$templateCache` so the view won't make another request to get the same file

```
$http.get('customView.html').then(function success(response) {
      $templateCache.put('customView.html', response.data);
      $scope.mainView = "'customView.html'";
}, function error(response) {
     $scope.mainView = "'defaultView.html'";
});
```

Comment: Ok... but I don't see when it could do the request twice ? and is there anything using a directive that can be done ?

Comment: Would do the request twice because `$http` makes one request...then so does `ng-include`